# How to instantiate a java generic class in a Rhino script?

Tags: javascript, java, generics, rhino

I try to marshall some JAXB objects in Rhino Javascript. Those JAXB Objects (top root is MyClass) are created from WSDL with `wsimport`. The Java side of the application doesn't know about MyClass.

My rhino script looks like this :

```
importPackage(Packages.javax.xml.bind);
importPackage(Packages.javax.xml.namespace);
...
  var myObj = new MyClass(); // MyClass has been generated from WSDL with wsimport
  var jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(myObj.getClass().getPackage().getName());
  var marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
  var strWriter = new StringWriter();
  var qName = new QName("xxx", "MyClass");
  var jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(qName, myObj.getClass(), myObj);
  marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, strWriter);
```

Unfortunately it gives a error saying the constructor of `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` is not found for arguments `object, java.lang.class, MyClass`.

I also tried without constructing the jaxbElement but marshaller launch an exception saying it cannot marshall due to lack of `XMLRootElement` is missing.

Is there a way either to indicate to rhino the type of JAXBElement or maybe a Java code that can be called WITHOUT knowing MyClass ?

The line causing the problem is:

`var jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(qName, pspApp.getClass(), pspApp);`

Comment: from what dependency are using `JAXBElement`? you might use a wrong import

Comment: don't think it is an import issue. This is really related to creating an instance of a Generic with a class in JS.

Comment: oh, really, I see, ok, just a shot in the dark: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12626143/5185646. might it be helpful? maybe it can be rewritten in JS somehow?

Comment: Try inlining the `qName` variable creation expression into 1st argument of the `JAXBElement` constructor expression. The interpreter can't find a constructor for `Object, Class, Object` tuple, because such constructor doesn't exist. The type of the first argument must be `QName`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fully qualify QName including its package name in the constructor like:

```
var qName = new javax.xml.namespace.QName("xxx", "MyClass");
```

Comment: Ok. It seems that the JS VM has a native type called QName the same name as the one imported from `javax.xml.namespace` package. When I fully qualify the QName type it works. I can't believe it first time :). Thanks a lot.