# @XmlRootElement not generated when one class extended by another

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have a three-tier inheritance structure being generated by JAXB: There's the basic `User` class, a `UserProfile` class that extends `User`, and a `UserSystem` class that extends `UserProfile`. I need both `UserProfile` and `UserSystem` to have the `@XmlRootElement` annotation so they can be marshalled. However, the schema below results in only `UserSystem` having `@XmlRootElement`.

To my knowledge, I have followed the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514110/how-to-generate-xmlrootelement-classes-for-base-types-in-xsd).

Here are the relevant parts of my schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.1" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true" typesafeEnumBase="xsd:string">
                <xjc:serializable uid="1"/>
                <xjc:superClass name="com.mycompany.common.BaseClass"/>
                <xjc:simple/>
            </jaxb:globalBindings>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>

<xsd:complexType name="User">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int" use="optional" default="0"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="firstname" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="lastname" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="UserProfile" type="UserProfile"/>

<xsd:complexType name="UserProfile">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="User">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="permissions" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xsd:element name="role" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>                   
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="UserSystem" type="UserSystem"/>

<xsd:complexType name="UserSystem">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="UserProfile">
            <xsd:attribute name="username" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="lastLoginDate" type="xsd:long" use="optional" default="0"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="locked" type="xsd:boolean" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The result is that `UserSystem` has the correct annotation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserSystem")
@XmlRootElement(name = "UserSystem")
public class UserSystem
    extends UserProfile
    implements Serializable
```

But `UserProfile` does not:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserProfile", propOrder = {
    "permissions",
    "roles"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    UserSystem.class
})
public class UserProfile
    extends User
    implements Serializable
```

I also have the `extension="true"` parameter in my Ant build script:

```
<target name="messages" depends="clean" description="Create java binding java files">
    <echo message="Compiling the schema..." />
    <xjc schema="${common.loc}/WebContent/master.xsd" package="com.l3com.apps.messages" destdir="${common.loc}/src" extension="true" />
</target>
```

I am using JAXB RI 2.2.11.

Comment: Your question says `@XmlRootElement` is missing,but title says `@XmlRootAttribute` was not generated.
Did you mean `@XmlRootElement` in title?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I certainly did. (Proofread everything except the title, apparently.) Sorry for the late reply; my inbox notifications were turned off.