# How to generate java class with @XmlRootElement from WSDL using xjc in command prompt

Tags: java, jaxb2, xjc

The xjc way of creating java package is

```
xjc -wsdl myWsdl.wsdl
```

This creates package like com

Then for generation of jar

```
jar cvf myJar.jar com/*
```

Any way to generate the java classes with `@XmlRootElement`
because my java class does not have it.

PS: using command prompt only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force generating `@XmlRootElement`, refer [How to generate @XmlRootElement Classes for Base Types in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945237/2565527) please.

However, I think you don't need to use `@XmlRootElement`. The post, [No @XmlRootElement generated by JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172942/2565527) indicates why `xjc` doesn't always generate `@XmlRootElement`.

Answer (score 1):

`xjc` tool does not have those options @XmlRootElement is not required.

Use the `JAXBElement` of the corresponding class in obj factory