# Jaxb: How do I generate ObjectFactory class?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm using Java 6, JaxB 2 and SpringSource Tool Suite (same as Eclipse).  I had a couple of Java classes I wrote, from which I used JaxB to generate an XML schema.  However, I'm noticing in order to use JaxB's ability to generate an XML document from Java objects, I need an ObjectFactory.

```
final Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
// Here is where I don't have an ObjectFactory defined
final JAXBElement<WebLeads> webLeadsElement  
         = (new ObjectFactory()).createWebLeads(webLeadsJavaObj);
```

How can I generate an ObjectFactory without blowing away the classes I already have now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This question may be referring to the role of `ObjectFactory` in creating a `JAXBContext`.  If you bootstrap a `JAXBContext` on a context path then it will check for an ObjectFactory in that location in order to determine the classes in that package:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

If you do not have an `ObjectFactory` but still wish to create you `JAXBContext` on a context path you can include a file called `jaxb.index` in that package listing files to be included in the `JAXBContext` (referenced classes will automatically pulled in):

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Alternatively you can bootstrap you `JAXBContext` on an array of classes instead of a context path:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

---

**Is ObjectFactory Required**

An `ObjectFactory` is not required, although even when starting from Java classes there are use cases where you can leverage a similar class annotated with [`@XmlRegistry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRegistry.html) in order to use the [`@XmlElementDecl`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementDecl.html) annotation.

**Creating an Instance of JAXBElement**

You can always create the `JAXBElement` directly:

```
final JAXBElement<WebLeads> webLeadsElement = new JAXBElement<WebLeads>(
    new QName("root-element-name"), 
    WebLeads.class, 
    webLeadsJavaObj);
```

**Alternative to JAXBElement**

Or since JAXBElement is simply used to provide root element information, you can annotate your `WebLeads` class with `@XmlRootElement`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root-element-name")
public class WebLeads {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Regarding your "Alternatie to JAXBElement" comment, how do I output the XML?  I added the root element, per your direction, but the call "marshaller.marshal( webLeads, writer );" results in a 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.myco.systems.leadsmonitor.domain" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index' exception.

Comment: @Dave - How are you bootstrapping your JAXBContext?  If you are bootstrapping on a context path (String) then you will need to include a file called jaxb.index in the same package as your domain classes with a carriage return list of class names (for an example see:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html), or you could create your JAXBContext on an array of classes (for an example see:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html).

Comment: I had been bootstrapping by creating a new instance using the package name, but when I changed it to create a new context based on the class everything worked.  Your links were really helpful.  Thanks, -

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need an ObjectFactory.

It's just a utility class XJC generates to make life easier in some cases.

Edit:
Reading your question, I guess you created the POJOs with JAXB annotations by hand.

Consider to add the XmlRootElement on the "root" class:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html

Here some more info:
[No @XmlRootElement generated by JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb)

Comment: Is it possible to suppress `ObjectFactory` creation in XJC?

Answer (score 1):

You don't 'need' a factory for the JaxB marshaller to function.  If you pass it an object with a list or a map variable, it will in fact marshall it correctly.  This is of course true only if you've correctly initilized the JaxB marshaller towards the object's class that you want to marshall.

You can create a factory, and that factory can create some specialized return (say you don't want it to return your public temp variables)