# Camel cxf: how to marshal incoming message to XML?

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, marshalling

I want to serialize the incoming message to XML. I'm starting from the camel-example-cxf-osgi example.

My Route:

```
JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat();

from("cxf:bean:reportIncident")
 .convertBodyTo(InputReportIncident.class)
 .marshal(jaxb)
 .bean(new MyBean2())
 .transform(constant(ok));
```

But I'm getting error and I'm at a loss:

```
java.io.IOException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.InputReportIncident nor any of its super class is  known to this context.
```

Appreciate any help. Thx.

Comment: Update: the "problem" got mysteriously solved. Now my object is converted to XML automatically. I didn't mention it before but I was getting a conversion exception when applying steps that would automatically transform it to a string. Now I'm getting a nice XML w/o having do do anything. My apologies, I've no idea what I did, I'm still relatively new to Camel.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the solution of Daniel, you could use

```
final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InputReportIncident.class);
final DataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat(jaxbContext);
```

This comes in handy if there is no `ObjectFactory` class. See [Jaxb: How do I generate ObjectFactory class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442312/jaxb-how-do-i-generate-objectfactory-class) for more general information about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point your to the package where you keep your jaxb classes, something like

```
DataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat("com.acme.model");
```

The exception says that the jaxb context doesn't know how to marshal the class `InputReportIncident.class`.