# Java web client CXF - JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, wsdl2java

I am using SpringBoot with Java14.  I am trying to write a SOAP client to consume an existing SOAP service.

I have created a SOAP client (consumer) below, but it gets an error when trying to run it.

I generated the related model objects from the wsdl with the following plugin in the pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/approval.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then I have the following client:

```
import com.travellinck.client.approval.ApprovalRequest;
import com.travellinck.client.approval.ApprovalResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;

@Service
public class SOAPClientRioImpl implements SOAPClient {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SOAPClientRioImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

    private WebServiceTemplate template;

    private static final String uri = "http://localhost:8088/approval?wsdl";

    @Override
    public ApprovalResponse submit(ApprovalRequest approvalRequest) {
        try {
            template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
            ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = (ApprovalResponse) template.marshalSendAndReceive(uri, approvalRequest);
            return approvalResponse;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("There was an error calling "+uri +" with approvalRequest. ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Everything compiles. When I run the client, I get the following **error**:

```
There was an error calling http://localhost:8088/approval?wsdl with approvalRequest. 

    org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException: JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
     - with linked exception:
    [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.travellinck.client.approval.ApprovalRequest" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:948) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:713) ~[spring-oxm-5.3.0-M1.jar:5.3.0-M1]
        at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.marshal(MarshallingUtils.java:81) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]

[com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.travellinck.client.approval.ApprovalRequest" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:948)
```

The generated ApprovalRequest.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import com.travellinck.client.approval.contact.PersonalInfo;
import com.travellinck.client.approval.evaluation.EvaluatorNomination;
import com.travellinck.client.approval.evaluation.strategy.EvaluationStrategy;


/**
 * <p>Java class for ApprovalRequest complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ApprovalRequest"&gt;
 *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
 *       &lt;sequence&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="requiredConclusionTime" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}dateTime" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="approvalType" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="businessRequest" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="supportingInfo" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="messageToEvaluator" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="organisation" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyURI"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="resubmissionOf" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="requestedBy" type="{http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/contact}PersonalInfo" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="nominatedEvaluator" type="{http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/evaluation}EvaluatorNomination" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="evaluationStrategy" type="{http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/evaluation/strategy}EvaluationStrategy" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *       &lt;/sequence&gt;
 *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
 *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
 * &lt;/complexType&gt;
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ApprovalRequest", propOrder = {
    "requiredConclusionTime",
    "approvalType",
    "businessRequest",
    "supportingInfo",
    "messageToEvaluator",
    "organisation",
    "resubmissionOf",
    "requestedBy",
    "nominatedEvaluator",
    "evaluationStrategy"
})
public class ApprovalRequest {

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar requiredConclusionTime;
    protected Integer approvalType;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Object businessRequest;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<Object> supportingInfo;
    protected String messageToEvaluator;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected String organisation;
    protected String resubmissionOf;
    protected PersonalInfo requestedBy;
    protected EvaluatorNomination nominatedEvaluator;
    protected EvaluationStrategy evaluationStrategy;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the requiredConclusionTime property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getRequiredConclusionTime() {
        return requiredConclusionTime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the requiredConclusionTime property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public void setRequiredConclusionTime(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.requiredConclusionTime = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the approvalType property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Integer }
     *     
     */
    public Integer getApprovalType() {
        return approvalType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the approvalType property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Integer }
     *     
     */
    public void setApprovalType(Integer value) {
        this.approvalType = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the businessRequest property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public Object getBusinessRequest() {
        return businessRequest;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the businessRequest property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public void setBusinessRequest(Object value) {
        this.businessRequest = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the supportingInfo property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the supportingInfo property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getSupportingInfo().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link Object }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Object> getSupportingInfo() {
        if (supportingInfo == null) {
            supportingInfo = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.supportingInfo;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the messageToEvaluator property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getMessageToEvaluator() {
        return messageToEvaluator;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the messageToEvaluator property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setMessageToEvaluator(String value) {
        this.messageToEvaluator = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the organisation property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getOrganisation() {
        return organisation;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the organisation property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrganisation(String value) {
        this.organisation = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the resubmissionOf property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getResubmissionOf() {
        return resubmissionOf;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the resubmissionOf property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setResubmissionOf(String value) {
        this.resubmissionOf = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the requestedBy property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link PersonalInfo }
     *     
     */
    public PersonalInfo getRequestedBy() {
        return requestedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the requestedBy property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link PersonalInfo }
     *     
     */
    public void setRequestedBy(PersonalInfo value) {
        this.requestedBy = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the nominatedEvaluator property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link EvaluatorNomination }
     *     
     */
    public EvaluatorNomination getNominatedEvaluator() {
        return nominatedEvaluator;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the nominatedEvaluator property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link EvaluatorNomination }
     *     
     */
    public void setNominatedEvaluator(EvaluatorNomination value) {
        this.nominatedEvaluator = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the evaluationStrategy property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link EvaluationStrategy }
     *     
     */
    public EvaluationStrategy getEvaluationStrategy() {
        return evaluationStrategy;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the evaluationStrategy property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link EvaluationStrategy }
     *     
     */
    public void setEvaluationStrategy(EvaluationStrategy value) {
        this.evaluationStrategy = value;
    }

}
```

WSDL

```
<!--  Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.5-b05 .  -->
<!--  Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.5-b05 .  -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service" name="ApprovalService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/evaluation/strategy" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=2"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/evaluation" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=3"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/contact" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=4"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8088/approval?xsd=5"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="submitRequestForApproval">
<part xmlns:ns1="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="approvalRequest" element="ns1:approvalRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="submitRequestForApprovalResponse">
<part xmlns:ns2="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="approvalResponse" element="ns2:approvalResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="UnsupportedBusinessRequest">
<part name="fault" element="tns:unsupportedBusinessRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="UnsupportedSupportingDocument">
<part name="fault" element="tns:unsupportedSupportingDocument"/>
</message>
<message name="getApprovalState">
<part xmlns:ns3="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="getApprovalStateRequest" element="ns3:getApprovalStateRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="getApprovalStateResponse">
<part xmlns:ns4="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="getApprovalStateResponse" element="ns4:getApprovalStateResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="UnknownApprovalRequest">
<part name="fault" element="tns:unknownApprovalRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="withdrawRequestForApproval">
<part xmlns:ns5="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="withdrawApprovalRequest" element="ns5:withdrawApprovalRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="withdrawRequestForApprovalResponse">
<part xmlns:ns6="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval" name="withdrawApprovalResponse" element="ns6:withdrawApprovalResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="InvalidRequest">
<part name="fault" element="tns:invalidRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="RequestNoLongerInProgress">
<part name="fault" element="tns:requestNoLongerInProgress"/>
</message>
<portType name="Approval">
<operation name="submitRequestForApproval">
<input wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/submitRequestForApprovalRequest" message="tns:submitRequestForApproval"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/submitRequestForApprovalResponse" message="tns:submitRequestForApprovalResponse"/>
<fault message="tns:UnsupportedBusinessRequest" name="UnsupportedBusinessRequest" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/submitRequestForApproval/Fault/UnsupportedBusinessRequest"/>
<fault message="tns:UnsupportedSupportingDocument" name="UnsupportedSupportingDocument" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/submitRequestForApproval/Fault/UnsupportedSupportingDocument"/>
</operation>
<operation name="getApprovalState">
<input wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/getApprovalStateRequest" message="tns:getApprovalState"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/getApprovalStateResponse" message="tns:getApprovalStateResponse"/>
<fault message="tns:UnknownApprovalRequest" name="UnknownApprovalRequest" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/getApprovalState/Fault/UnknownApprovalRequest"/>
</operation>
<operation name="withdrawRequestForApproval">
<input wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApprovalRequest" message="tns:withdrawRequestForApproval"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApprovalResponse" message="tns:withdrawRequestForApprovalResponse"/>
<fault message="tns:InvalidRequest" name="InvalidRequest" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApproval/Fault/InvalidRequest"/>
<fault message="tns:RequestNoLongerInProgress" name="RequestNoLongerInProgress" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApproval/Fault/RequestNoLongerInProgress"/>
<fault message="tns:UnknownApprovalRequest" name="UnknownApprovalRequest" wsam:Action="http://www.travellinck.com/client/approval/service/Approval/withdrawRequestForApproval/Fault/UnknownApprovalRequest"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="ApprovalPortBinding" type="tns:Approval">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="submitRequestForApproval">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="UnsupportedBusinessRequest">
<soap:fault name="UnsupportedBusinessRequest" use="literal"/>
</fault>
<fault name="UnsupportedSupportingDocument">
<soap:fault name="UnsupportedSupportingDocument" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
<operation name="getApprovalState">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="UnknownApprovalRequest">
<soap:fault name="UnknownApprovalRequest" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
<operation name="withdrawRequestForApproval">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="InvalidRequest">
<soap:fault name="InvalidRequest" use="literal"/>
</fault>
<fault name="RequestNoLongerInProgress">
<soap:fault name="RequestNoLongerInProgress" use="literal"/>
</fault>
<fault name="UnknownApprovalRequest">
<soap:fault name="UnknownApprovalRequest" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="ApprovalService">
<port name="ApprovalPort" binding="tns:ApprovalPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8088/approval"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the help of Joe, I have added the following to the POM:

```
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/approval.wsdl</wsdl>
    <bindingFiles>
        <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/BindingFile.xjb</bindingFile> 
    </bindingFiles>
    <extraargs><extraarg>-xjc-Xannotate</extraarg></extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
```

BindingFile.xjb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox xjc"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
               xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
               xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="approval.wsdl#types1" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ApprovalRequest']">
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="approvalRequest"/>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='ApprovalResponse']">
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="approvalResponse"/>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

However, when I do a maven build, I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: file:/Users/richardmarais/IdeaProjects/nexct-approval-service/src/main/resources/wsdl/BindingFile.xjb [12,73]: XPath evaluation of "//xs:complexType[@name='ApprovalRequest']" results in empty target node
[WARNING] file:/Users/richardmarais/IdeaProjects/nexct-approval-service/src/main/resources/wsdl/BindingFile.xjb [17,74]: XPath evaluation of "//xs:complexType[@name='ApprovalResponse']" results in empty target node
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by not binding, but rather converting the object to a jaxb element.

```
        template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);

        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<ApprovalRequest> jaxbApprovalRequest = objectFactory.createApprovalRequest(approvalRequest);

        ApprovalResponse response = (ApprovalResponse) template
                .marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:8088/approval", jaxbApprovalRequest);

        System.out.println(response);
        return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide a binding file so that the generated class gets the `@XMLRootElement` annotation so that it can be unmarshalled by the default marshaller.

From the second answer here:
[I would like to add @XmlRoot annotation on CXF codegen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239587/i-would-like-to-add-xmlroot-annotation-on-cxf-codegen)

Add the following fragments to POM.XML (replacing the binding file with the name you choose):

```
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/approval.wsdl</wsdl>
    <bindingFiles>
        <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/BindingFile.xjb</bindingFile> 
    </bindingFiles>
    <extraargs><extraarg>-xjc-Xannotate</extraarg></extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
```

XJB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox xjc"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance">

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="CP_Ablakido_1.wsdl#types1" node="/xs:schema"> 
       <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='InputMapping1']">
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="GetList_11"/>
          </annox:annotate>
      </jaxb:bindings>    
      <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='OutputMapping1']">
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="GetList_11Response"/>
          </annox:annotate>
      </jaxb:bindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Add these dependencies to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, I am having a look. I am little confused to be honest, but trying to work it out.

Comment: The second answer this one may provide a bit better detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810116/missing-xmlrootelement-when-creating-a-client-from-a-wsdl

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand correctly, it says I need to define the schema. Unfortunately the WSDL is coming from an application I don't have control over, and that defines the schema.

Comment: Maybe this one then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239587/i-would-like-to-add-xmlroot-annotation-on-cxf-codegen

Comment: I am really struggling to see how to do this, because it required me to define the schema (jaxb:bindings), but I don't have control over this.

Comment: I am thinking maybe I need to marshal the object to a xml string first before sending it to the service.

Comment: Updating answer. I think the second link has what you need that doesn't require changing the schema

Comment: Thanks for your answer above, excuse my ignorance before, but that makes it much clearer what I need to do.. Only issue is now that I have added the binding, I get a maven build error.  I am just adding it to the original question....

Comment: It fails to execute goal `wsdl2java` with `BadCommandLineException: unrecognized parameter -Xannotate`.

Comment: Missed some dependencies from the other post. Updated answer

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you help.

Comment: It looks like this is on the right track, I am just trying to make the binding file fit my wsdl.  I now get: `XPath evaluation of "//xs:complexType[@name='ApprovalRequest']" results in empty target node` and `XPath evaluation of "//xs:complexType[@name='ApprovalResponse']" results in empty target node`.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, I just need to fix the mapping of the binding file to the schema to confirm.  I have added a question here for help on how to do it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641071/xpath-evaluation-error-trying-to-bind-to-a-schema