# How to get JAXB schemagen to allow multiple element names for one @XmlRootElement class

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

This is kind of the opposite direction of questions like [No @XmlRootElement generated by JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb). Basically I want to run schemagen and have two global elements of the same type.

```
<xs:element name="root1" type="tns:sameType"/>
<xs:element name="root2" type="tns:sameType"/>
```

I understand how to marshal things with JAXBElement but I'm at a loss on how to get the schema generated correctly. In my mind it would look something like the following snippet (@XmlRootElements is fictional).

```
@XmlRootElements(value = {
    @XmlRootElement(name="root1", namespace="urn:example"),
    @XmlRootElement(name="root2", namespace="urn:example")
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on a class annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

**ObjectFactory**

The `@XmlElementDecl` annotation is used when a type has multiple global elements corresponding to it. The annotation is placed on `create` methods on a class annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.  When a model is generated from an XML schema this class is always called `ObjectFactory`.

```
package forum14845035;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="root1")
    public JAXBElement<SameType> createRoot1(SameType sameType) {
        return new JAXBElement<SameType>(new QName("urn:example", "root1"), SameType.class, sameType);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name="root2")
    public JAXBElement<SameType> createRoot2(SameType sameType) {
        return new JAXBElement<SameType>(new QName("urn:example", "root2"), SameType.class, sameType);
    }

}
```

**SameType**

In this use case no annotations are required on the domain class.

```
package forum14845035;

public class SameType {

}
```

**package-info**

We will leverage the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification for our model.

```
@XmlSchema(namespace="urn:example", elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package forum14845035;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Demo**

```
package forum14845035;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SameType.class, ObjectFactory.class);
        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri,
                    String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" targetNamespace="urn:example" xmlns:tns="urn:example" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="root1" type="tns:sameType"/>

  <xs:element name="root2" type="tns:sameType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="sameType">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I've been using jaxb.index and didn't even think to look at an ObjectFactory as a possible avenue.