# Marshalling the Java objects (without @XmlRootElement) to JSON via Jettison

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jettison

I have done the marshalling of an JAXB object (Which contains @XmlRootElement) to JSON using Jettison. But I can not convert a simple java object which has no annotations like @XmlRootElement to JSON. I would like to know "Is it mandatory to have that @XmlRootElement to marshall an object to JSON?"

I am getting the following Exception when I try to marshall the java object to Json

```
com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "simpleDetail" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Looks like you might need the @XmlRootElement, at least according to the error message. But you could use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org)'s JSON serialization to get around it.

Comment: @hd1 : Thanks for the response. Yes we can do it., If we use XStream or GSON. But I need to use Jettison only to do it. Is it not possible here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The JAXB (JSR-222) specification does not cover JSON-binding.  Instead of using a JAXB implementation with the Jettison library, you could use EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) that offers native JSON-binding.  Below is an example.

**JAVA MODEL**

**Foo**

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private List<Bar> mylist;

}
```

**Bar**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Bar {

    private int id;
    private String name;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**DEMO CODE**

**Demo**

MOXy does not require the `@XmlRootElement` annotation, and you can use the `JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT` property to tell MOXy to ignore the presence of any `@XmlRootElement` annotations.  When the root element is ignored you need to use an `unmarshal` method that takes a class parameter to specify the type you are unmarshalling.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Foo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum15404528/input.json");
        Foo foo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Foo.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

We see that no root element is present in the input or output.

```
{
   "mylist" : [ {
      "id" : 104,
      "name" : "Only one found"
   } ]
}
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: @BDoughan : Yes I have tried this with eclipseLink and it works well. But I need to implement it using JETTISON :( .Plz guide me to achieve this using JETTISON.

Comment: @user1933756 - I'm not sure if it is possible with Jettison.  I have edited your questions title and tags to include Jettison to try and attract the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thnk u Blaise : I have read this http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html . Here it is done using JETTISON

Comment: @user1933756 - I'm not sure if you noticed, but that post is from my blog.

Comment: Yes :) it is from your blog. I like to confirm whether it is done purely using JETTISON?

Comment: @user1933756 - The JSON output in that particular post is done only with Jettison.  If the collection in that example had been size one it would not have been output as a JSON array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26152/discussion-between-user1933756-and-blaise-doughan)

Answer (score 0):

Just read that `@XmlRootElement` is not necessary always. Please read [this blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/03/why_does_jaxb_p.html), at the bottom you will find how it's done without `@XmlRootElement`.
Also go through the answers in the post [No @XmlRootElement generated by JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb).