# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element. Expected elements are (none)

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am getting this error, while unmarshalling a string. I have created Java files using JAXB.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DocumentType.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
// Input string posted below
DocumentType dType = (DocumentType) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader("input string"));
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd", local:"document"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:238)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1048)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3065)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at JaxbTest.main(JaxbTest.java:19)
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="document" type="tns:documentType"></xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="documentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="businessCard" type="tns:businessCardType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="businessCardType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="field" type="tns:fieldType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="fieldType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="characters" type="tns:charactersType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="fieldComponents" type="tns:fieldComponentsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="tns:typeType"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="typeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Name"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Phone"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Mobile"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Fax"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Company"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Job"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Address"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Email"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Web"></xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Text"></xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="charactersType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="char" type="tns:charType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="charType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="suspicious" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"></xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="fieldComponentsType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="fieldComponent" type="tns:fieldComponentType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="fieldComponentType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="type" type="tns:fieldComponentTypeType"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="fieldComponentTypeType">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="FirstName"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="MiddleName"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="LastName"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="ExtraName"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="PhonePrefix"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="PhoneCountryCode"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="PhoneCode"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="PhoneBody"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="PhoneExtension"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="ZipCode"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="Country"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="City"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="StreetAddress"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="JobPosition"></xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="JobDepartment"></xs:enumeration>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Input string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://ocrsdk.com/schema/recognizedBusinessCard-1.0.xsd">
<businessCard>
<field type="Phone">
  <value>783-37-00</value>
</field>
<field type="Phone">
  <value>783-37-01</value>
</field>
<field type="Fax">
  <value>783-26-63</value>
</field>
<field type="Email">
  <value>john_sm@abbyy.com</value>
</field>
<field type="Web">
  <value>www.abbyy.com</value>
</field>
<field type="Address">
  <value>Otradnaya str., 2b, bld.6, 127273, Moscow, Russia</value>
</field>
<field type="Name">
  <value>John Smith</value>
</field>
<field type="Company">
  <value>ABBYY Headquarters</value>
</field>
<field type="Job">
  <value>Product Analyst</value>
</field>
<field type="Text">
  <value>ABBYY ABBYY Headquarters John Smith Product Analyst ABBYY Headquarters Otradnaya str., 2b, bld.6, 127273, Moscow, Russia Tel: 783-37-00 Fax: 783-26-63 john_sm@abbyy.com www.abbyy.com </value>
</field>
</businessCard>
</document>
```

Answer (score 149):

When you generate a JAXB model from an XML Schema, global elements that correspond to named complex types will have that metadata captured as an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on a create method in the `ObjectFactory` class.  Since you are creating the `JAXBContext` on just the `DocumentType` class this metadata isn't being processed.  If you generated your JAXB model from an XML Schema then you should create the `JAXBContext` on the generated package name or `ObjectFactory` class to ensure all the necessary metadata is processed.

**Example solution:**

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(my.generatedschema.dir.ObjectFactory.class);
DocumentType documentType = ((JAXBElement<DocumentType>) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(inputStream)).getValue();
```

Comment: Works fine. unmarshaller.unmarshal() will return JAXBElement<DocumentType> instead of DocumentType. Call getValue() to get the wrapped object.

Comment: In my case, calling the imported root element required `unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();  
final Object object = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("path/to/data.xml"));  
final DocumentType cd = (DocumentType)object;`

Comment: Second step looks like this: `DocumentType doc = ((JAXBElement<DocumentType>) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
                inputStream)).getValue();`

Comment: I got the same error as before. However I was able to use the anonymous root object method suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15117152/1717259

Answer (score 40):

Alternatively if you want to persist in using the `DocumentType` class.
Then you could just add the following annotation on top of your DocumentType class.

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="document")
```

Note: the String value `"document"` refers to the name of the root tag of the xml message.

Comment: Thanks, dude. After hunting about hours for a solution on this situation, the @XmlRootElement fixed the problem. I'm wondering why this behavior should be like this. Does it really make sense to force this annotation under unmarshalling process?

Comment: @Miere Now that I think about it. In the world of webservices, RPC-style automatically provides a wrapping node, where as document-style webservices require an explicit declaration. So, it's always been an area of discussion.

Comment: I am using xjc in jdk1.6.0_45 to generate POJO from XSD. The root POJO generated by xjc is missing @XmlRootElement(name="RootName"). Add this line on top manually and unmarshal is successful.

Comment: It's always the owner class that defines the xml tag name of its associations (e.g. using `@XmlElement(name='...')`). So, a class does not define its own xml tag name. But since the root element does not have a parent node, that poses a problem for the root element. **Several solutions exist:** XJC assumes that you will use its `ObjectFactory`. It defines the name of the rootnode using the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation in its `ObjectFactory`. But if you don't want to use the `ObjectFactory`, then the above annotation (i.e. `@XmlRootElement`) is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: I needed to add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` too.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I got this error when I imported incorrectly `jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement`. The correct one should be `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement`

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons for this error is the use of the jaxb implementation from the jdk. I am not sure why such a problem can appear in pretty simple xml parsing situations. You may use the latest version of the jaxb library from a public maven repository:

http://mvnrepository.com

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case we were getting UnmarshalException because a wrong Java package was specified in the following. The issue was resolved once the right package was in place:

```
@Bean
public Unmarshaller tmsUnmarshaller() {
    final Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller
            .setPackagesToScan("java.package.to.generated.java.classes.for.xsd");
    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, contrary to Tuan Hoang's solution, I had to use `jakarta.xml.bind` instead of `javax.xml.bind`. Maybe it's related to the JDK used in the project, which is in my case JDK11.