# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"id"). Expected elements are (none)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, deserialization

**Important**: I want to advance that I already read [javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element. Expected elements are (none)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586737/javax-xml-bind-unmarshalexception-unexpected-element-expected-elements-are-no) and tried the suggested solutions without success.

---

I tried to deserialize an `XML` into a `JAXB` class generated with `xjc`. This is the code:

```java
final GeocodPlugin plugin;

final JAXBContext xmlContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(GeocodPlugin.class);
final Unmarshaller xmlDeserializer = xmlContext.createUnmarshaller();

try (final Reader reader = new StringReader(xml)) {
    plugin = (GeocodPlugin) xmlDeserializer.unmarshal(reader);
}
```

This is the error:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"id"). Expected elements are (none)

This is the `XML`, created by another program (`YAWL`). I put [newline] only to signal there's a newline at the start and the end of the `XML` string:

```
[newline]
  <id>myid</id>
  <jsonrpc>2.0</jsonrpc>
  <method>geocod</method>
  <params>
    <userId>user</userId>
    <imagePathList>a16274073a714a20b434895e94e8c333</imagePathList>
    <imageIdList>a16274073a714a20b434895e94e8c333</imageIdList>
    <outputPathRoot>/home/database/share/CODELET_20190816144726</outputPathRoot>
    <preserveDirectoryMinDepth>-1</preserveDirectoryMinDepth>
    <preserveDirectoryMaxDepth>-1</preserveDirectoryMaxDepth>
    <polarisation>ANY</polarisation>
    [...other params...]
  </params>
[newline]
```

This is the `JAXB` class generated by `xjc`:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "GeocodPlugin", propOrder = {
        "id",
        "jsonrpc",
        "method",
        "params"
    }
)

public class GeocodPlugin {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String id;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String jsonrpc;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "geocod")
    protected String method;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected GeocodParameters params;

    [getters and setters]
}
```

`ObjectFactory` is not useful, since it's simply a factory with no additional annotations. It seems it continues to be generated only for backward compatibility. Anyway I tried also with it and I get the same problem.

I also tried to surround the `XML` with a `<root>` element and add `@XmlRootElement(name = "root")` to the class `GeocodePlugin`, but it gives me an absurd error:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"root"). Expected elements are ({parameters}root)

where `parameters` is the namespace of the objects used as type of the `params` element, declared in the original `XSD`...

This is the original `XSD`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema jxb:version="2.0" targetNamespace="parameters" xmlns:enumerations="enumerations" xmlns:parameters="parameters" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="my.plugin.package"/>
      </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:import namespace="enumerations" schemaLocation="total_enumerations_schema.xsd"/>
  <!-- @author Marco Sulla -->
  <xs:complexType name="GeocodParameters">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="userId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1000" minOccurs="1" name="imagePathList" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1000" minOccurs="0" name="imageIdList" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element default="-1" name="preserveDirectoryMinDepth" nillable="false" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element default="-1" name="preserveDirectoryMaxDepth" nillable="false" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element default="ANY" name="polarisation" nillable="false" type="enumerations:PolarisationEnum"/>
      [other params]
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="GeocodPlugin">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="jsonrpc" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element default="geocod" name="method" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="params" type="parameters:GeocodParameters"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm using `Java` 8 (Azul ZuluFx 8.0.202) and `xjc` 2.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make it working. I had to add a `<root>` or whatever enclosing tag to the `XML`, add `@XmlRootElement` to the Java class (I don't know why `xjc` does not add it by default) and remove `package-info.java` generated by `xjc`, that contains:

```java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "parameters")
package my.plugin.package;
```

that I don't understand well its usefulness in the Java code. I also tried to add `<parameters:root>` and I get the error `namespace not defined`.