# unable to marshal type as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation for auto generated classes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, schema

I need to validate Class object against my schema in which I have provided regular expression to validate fields for auto generated JAXB classes. When I try to validate my class object I get below error:

> unable to marshal type "xyz" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Here is the code that I use to validate my autogenerated class object:

```
jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
source = new JAXBSource(jc, obj);
Schema schema = schemaInjector.getSchema();
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(source);
```

Is there any other way I can solve this?

Answer (score 97):

If your class does not have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation then you can wrap it in an instance of `JAXBElement`.  If you generated your classes from an XML Schema then the generated `ObjectFactory` may have a convenience method for you.

I have written more about this use case on my [blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html):

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have modified my code as per solution on your blog but I am still getting the same error. modified code is:     `QName qName = new QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", obj.toString());` `JAXBElement<T> e = createJAXBElement(qName, obj.getClass(), obj);` `jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(e.getValue().getClass());` `Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();` `source = new JAXBSource(jc, m.getClass());` `Schema schema = schemaInjector.getSchema();`
`Validator validator = schema.newValidator();` `validator.validate(source);`     _Please advice_

Comment: I found this answer helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2172942/58363 It gives alternate wording to @Blaise-doughan 's answer.

Answer (score 23):

I solved this problem by using the `ObjectFactory` class as shown in the example below:

```
PostTransaction transactionRequest = new PostTransaction();
//Some code here

JAXBElement<PostTransaction> jAXBElement = new ObjectFactory().createPostTransaction(transactionRequest);
 try {
JAXBElement<PostTransactionResponse> aXBElementResponse = (JAXBElement<PostTransactionResponse>) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("wsdlUrl", jAXBElement, new SoapActionCallback("soapMethodName"));
```

Comment: Easiest solution

Comment: In my case, the analog ".createPostTransaction () " has no parameters((

Comment: Best answer..and clean.  if anyone wondering how to create the ObjectFactory().createXyZ you can build the jaxbObjects using jaxb maven plugin

Comment: From where is the PostTransaction? I don't have that

Comment: I am still getting same error `com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.example.camel.client.stub.Generic" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation`. Can you please help?
I have a question posted in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178871/unable-to-marshal-type-classname-as-an-element-because-it-is-missing-an-xmlro?noredirect=1#comment134343257_76178871

Answer (score 14):

I suggest you to use Maven plugin `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to generate classes from a `.xsd` file. Use a binding file e.g. `.xjb` to add annotations `@XmlRootElement`. Example:

Binding file:

```xml
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net">

  <globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable uid="12343" />
        <xjc:simple/>
  </globalBindings>
  
</bindings>
```

POM (Maven plugin config):

```xml
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                <arg>-nv</arg>
            </args>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
            <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/xjb</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingIncludes>
                <include>*.xjb</include>
            </bindingIncludes>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.xsd</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
            <debug>true</debug>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-namespace-prefix</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

See [Maven JAXB2 Plugin User Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20171029123228/http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide)

Comment: Note that `<xjc:simple/>` is the relevant piece here which will add the `@XmlRootElement` annotation. This is a vendor customization in the JAXB RI, see here: https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/vendorCustomizations.html. It does more than just add this annotation. If you only want the `@XmlRootElement`, you can use the jaxb2-basics-annotate extension.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue due to legacy wsdl that doesn't have xsd schema
 inside wsdl definition. I solved this issue by having two maven plugins to
 generate operations from wsdl as well DTD from xsd file as below and 
for marshalling `new ObjectFactory().createHandShake(new HandShake());`

```
  public boolean handShake() {
        JAXBElement<HandShake> request = new ObjectFactory().createHandShake(new HandShake());
        logger.info(String.format("request: {0}", "handshake request"));
        logger.debug("sending request");
        HandShakeResponse handShakeResponse = ((JAXBElement<HandShakeResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive(request, new SoapActionCallback(
                        "urn:handShake"))).getValue();
        logger.debug("receive response");
        return handShakeResponse.isReturn();
    }

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>${contextPathWSDL}</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>${merchant.WSDL}</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsds</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.xsd</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <generatePackage>${contextPathXSD}</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/DTD</generateDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: And how to solve this problem using gradle?