# Consume SOAP WS in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, soap, spring-boot, marshalling, jaxb2

I'm trying to consume some SOAP web services within a spring boot application. I've imported the ws's stubs and I've followed WebServiceTemplate, as explained [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service). Unfortunately, when making requests I get an exception:

> 2017-01-13 12:13:47.146 ERROR 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException: JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: no se ha podido canalizar el tipo "com.dashboard.dto.ComprobarSolicitud" como un elemento, porque le falta una anotación @XmlRootElement]] with root cause

The "ComprobarSolicitud" class is the following one:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "comprobarSolicitud", propOrder = {
    "username",
    "passwd",
    "nif",
    "fechaDesde",
    "fechaHasta",
    "cantidad"
})
public class ComprobarSolicitud {

    protected String username;
    protected String passwd;
    protected String nif;
    protected String fechaDesde;
    protected String fechaHasta;
    protected int cantidad;

    // ...getters and setters
```

WebServiceGatewaySupport class:

```
public class PerClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PadronClient.class);

    public ComprobarSolicitudResponse comprobarSolicitudes(String pNif, LocalDate pFechaInicio, LocalDate pFechaFin){
    ComprobarSolicitud request = new ComprobarSolicitud();
    // .. set operations to request

    ComprobarSolicitudResponse response = (ComprobarSolicitudResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
    .marshalSendAndReceive(
                    "https://ws.dir.com:8444/PerExterno/perExterno",
                    request,
                    new SoapActionCallback("http://service.ws.per.company.com/ExternalWS/comprobarSolicitudResponse"));

    return response;
}
```

}

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class PerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller(){
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.dashboard.dto.per");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public PerClient padronClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller){
        PerClient client = new PerClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://ws.dir.com:8444/PerExterno");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

}
```

Should I create a custom marshaller? But, how? I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24520105/828551), where it's said that in case @XmlRootElement annotation is missing, I should wrap it in an instance of JAXBElement.

Thank you

**SOLUTION!**

The exception was self-explanatory, and the solution was straightforward, as just PerClient class was necessary to be modified as follows:

```
public class PerClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PadronClient.class);

    public ComprobarSolicitudResponse comprobarSolicitudes(String pNif, LocalDate pFechaInicio, LocalDate pFechaFin){
    ComprobarSolicitud request = new ComprobarSolicitud();
    // .. set operations to request

    ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
    JAXBElement<ComprobarSolicitud> reqjaxb = of.createComprobarSolicitud(request);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    JAXBElement<ComprobarSolicitudResponse> response = (ComprobarSolicitudResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
    .marshalSendAndReceive(
                    "https://ws.dir.com:8444/PerExterno/perExterno",
                    reqjaxb ,
                    new SoapActionCallback("http://service.ws.per.company.com/ExternalWS/comprobarSolicitudResponse"));

    return response.getValue();
}
```

}

Comment: You already have the answer... Wrap it in a `JAXBElement`.

Comment: I've wrapped it, now I'm testing it.

Comment: Solved! I'd the answer in front of my f-face. Updating the question with solution. Thanks @M.Deinum