# Two Element form of Unmarshaller.unmarshal()

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have seen the following syntax in various stack overflow postings and in blog entries:

```
JAXBElement<SomeClass> sc = unmarshaller.unmarshal(is, SomeClass.class);
```

So why does eclipse give me a compilation error when I try to use this syntax?  And why is this syntax not in the api, which you can read [at this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html)?

Here is the compilation error:

```
The method unmarshal(Node, Class<T>) in the type Unmarshaller  
is not applicable for the arguments (FileInputStream, Class<SomeClass>)
```

Here is a complete method that would use the above syntax:

```
public void unmarshal() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    try {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("path/to/some.xml");
        JAXBElement<SomeClass> sc = unmarshaller.unmarshal(is, SomeClass.class);//error here
        System.out.println("title is: "+sc.getValue().getTitle());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

This syntax is given in examples where a developer needs to unmarshal xml that does not contain a defined root element.  One example is Sayantam's answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb).

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: Please also post where you saw this example (links).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to wrong type argument, FileInputStream instead of Node.

This method is more appropriate to unmarshal a piece of the xml. When you want to parse the entire file, use the unsmarshal(File) method.

```
public void unmarshal() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    try {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("path/to/some.xml");
        SomeClass sc = (SomeClass) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
        System.out.println("title is: "+sc.getValue().getTitle());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

If you don't want to make a cast, try this:

```
public void unmarshal() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    try {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();

        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource("path/to/some.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(streamSource);
        JAXBElement<SomeClass> sc = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, SomeClass.class);//error here
        System.out.println("title is: "+sc.getValue().getTitle());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: I had to change your `XMLInputFactory.newFactory()` to `XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()`, but otherwise your second example does the trick.  Thank you.  +1