# Inject annotation with xjc and custom binding file

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, xjc, xjb

Well, I've got this external (and old) WSDL structured like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:tns="...custom namespace..."
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    targetNamespace="...custom namespace..."
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="...custom namespace...">
            <s:element name="...">
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="...">
            </s:element>
            <s:complexType name="CustomClassName">
            ...
```

I'm creating Java classes from this WSDL with xjc.

The request I'm using from this WSDL responds with plain XML beginning with **CustomClassName**, but this class is not annotated with **XMLRootElement**.

When I manually add this annotation to this class, my code works just fine.

But I want to add the annotation by using a custom binding file when calling xjc, and a.t.m. I can't get this to work. My current custom binding file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox" version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="...wsdl filename..." node="//s:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="s:complexType[@name='CustomClassName']">
            <annox:annotate>
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" />
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

(I've tried different syntaxes I found but the class is still not annotated.)

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Seems like customizations don't get attached to WSDL. I recall there were a couple of questions about the same problem.

Comment: Since it's not a solution for this question I'm posting it as a comment: I've found another way in these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb/2172942#2172942 (no XMLRootElement annotation needed when working with JAXBElement and XMLStreamReader)