# Get rid of JAXBElement from jaxb-generated code?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have an xsd from which I am generating some java code:

```
<xs:element name="full-account-v2" >
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ban" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="status" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This has been working ok and gives me a generated class called FullAccountV2.

I want to use the same complex type elsewhere, so I thought I would create a named complex type in the xsd file, and refer to it like this:

```
<xs:element name="full-account-v2" type="fullAccountV2Type"/>
```

The complex type is defined as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name="fullAccountV2Type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ban" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="status" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now suddenly the unmarshaller stops working. The following xml was unmarshalling just fine to a FullAccountV2:

```
<er-response id="100058" version="2">
  <payload>
   <full-account-v2>
    <ban>BAN_P146058461158163004</ban>
     <status>401</status>
   </full-account-v2>
  </payload>
</er-response>
```

But now that class no longer appears, and the xml is unmarshalled by jaxb to a `JAXBElement` with `Qname` `full-account-v2` and `declaredType` `FullAccountV2Type`.

ErResponse and Payload are defined elsewhere as:

```
<xs:complexType name="payloadType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I tried defining the type in a separate xml file to the element declaration, but got the same result.

How can such a simple refactor have caused me 8 hours of struggle?  What am I doing wrong?

NB this appears to be the inverse of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/)

Comment: 'stops working' is not a helpful phrase.  Detail the specific error message or condition

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<xs:element name="full-account-v2" type="fullAccountV2" />
<xs:complexType name="fullAccountV2">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ban" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="status" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now, JAXB schema compiler will generate an artifact by `FullAccountV2` name as earlier.

It is also okay to have the `name` and `type` have the same value i.e, `FullAccountV2`. Below change also works fine -

```
<!-- one is element and other is complexType -->
<xs:element name="fullAccountV2" type="fullAccountV2" />
<xs:complexType name="fullAccountV2">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ban" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="status" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Above schema definition will also generate an artifact `FullAccountV2` as earlier. Whatever we assign to `type` is used by schema compiler to derive artifact name.

This is also noticeable otherwise if you are generating schema `xsd` using `schemagen`. For example - for the class definition shown below

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Pojo {
    public Pojo p;
}
```

`schemagen` generates below schema definition

```
<xs:element name="pojo" type="pojo"/>
<xs:complexType name="pojo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="p" type="pojo" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Notice, `name` and `type` have the same value i.e, class name by default.

Comment: Fails with:   `javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.mycompany.global.er.decoupling.binding.response.v2.FullAccountV2" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]`