# I have @xmlrootelement , but keep getting this exception: unable to marshal type as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, xmlroot

I am trying to `marshall/unmarshall` a class which does not have `@xmlrootelement`. Can anyone help ? The marshaller I am using is of type Jaxb2Marshaller of the Spring's `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb`  Most of the solutions present are of type `javax.xml.bind` `Marshaller` and `JAXBContext`. Need help in `marshalling` a Java Class which does not have any `@xmlrootelement` provided, generated from XML using Spring's `JAXB2MARSHALLER`.

I am not able to add the `@xmlrootelement` because this is an external `.jar`

I have tried all these solutions which actually provide a way of marshalling/unmarshalling using javax instead of spring

[unable to marshal type as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation for auto generated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519449/unable-to-marshal-type-as-an-element-because-it-is-missing-an-xmlrootelement-an)

[Unable to marshal type as XML element because @XmlRootElement annotation is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050316/unable-to-marshal-type-as-xml-element-because-xmlrootelement-annotation-is-miss/37050473)

Including this which has a very neat explanation but uses Marshaller instead of JaxB2Marshaller

https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/marshal-without-xmlrootelement/

Class need to undergo Marshalling without `@xmlrootelement`

PartnerRequest.java class which has `@xmlrootelement`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "",
    propOrder = {"partnerCdId", "clientProductCode"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "PartnerRequest"
)
public class PartnerRequest



    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(
        name = "Partner",
       )
    public class Partner{
    }
```

Exception I am getting is as below:

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.svc.partner.v1.PartnerRequest" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:933)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:709)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.marshal(MarshallingUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$2.doWithMessage(WebServiceTemplate.java:395)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:539)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:386)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:380)
    at com.vmd.services.BaseService.marshallSendAndReceive(BaseService.java:53)
    at com.vmd.services.PartnerServiceImpl.getPartner(PartnerServiceImpl.java:27)
    at com.vmd.services.PartnerServiceImplTest.ShouldGetPartner(PartnerServiceImplTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException: null
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:236)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:705)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.svc.partner.v1.PartnerRequest" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:234)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Also, Remember we need to Marshall it using Jaxb2Mashaller not Marshaller. This is an external jar/dependency not editable code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did it resolve your query ?

Comment: It actually did not resolve my Query, But seems that I have a PartnerRequest class, which is as follows:  `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "",
    propOrder = {"partnerCdId", "clientProductCode"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "PartnerRequest"
)
public class PartnerRequest`     This has `@xmlrootelement` but still it is complaining about missing annotation

Comment: Updated my issue. Do let me know, I have `@xmlrootelement` in the PartnerRequest, still exception shows issue for Partner Request not having it

Comment: Having a `@XmlRootElement`completely reverted the original question. My original solution works for no `@XmlRootElement`. Let me include handling of one with `@XmlRootElement`.

Comment: I updated my git repo with the example for one with root element as well. If you still see the issue look for how the Jaxb2Marshaller is initialized & what classes/packages are bound in the context ? Also if you don't have conflict in the PartnerRequest class in the application. If root element is present, it should work without any issues.

Comment: Did it resolve you query ? Were you able to achieve the desired result ? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: I was able to resolve it, but definitely your concern helped. Thank you

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the similar exception using JAxBElement:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
```

Please try it once, if it is not working then kindly share a sample XSD for further investigation.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I've tried that. `JAXBCONTEXT` is from `javax.xml.bind`. Need something from SpringFramework

Answer (score 0):

Marshalling & Unmarshalling can't be done without parser to know the root element. So when you don't have `@XmlRootElement` in the data class, you circumvent using `JAXBElement`, where you provide your model class wrapped in it, so the marshaller know the what source class structure to refer when parsing.

I have included below the working example of using `JAXBElement` with spring `Jaxb2Marshaller`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class XmlTransformationNoRoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(XmlTransformationNoRoot.class, args);
    }

}

@Component
class TestTransformation implements CommandLineRunner {

    public void run(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

        //marshalling
        String testXML = marshallXml(new Partner("HelloWorld"));
        System.out.println("Marshalled : " + testXML);

        //unmarshalling
        System.out.println("Unmarshalled : " + unmarshallXml(testXML, Partner.class));
    }

    public <T> String marshallXml(T object) throws JAXBException {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Result result = new StreamResult(sw);
        jaxb2Marshaller().marshal(new JAXBElement(
                new QName(object.getClass().getPackage().getName(), object.getClass().getSimpleName()),
                object.getClass(), object), result);
        return sw.toString();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T unmarshallXml(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = jaxb2Marshaller();
        //this line voids singleton use of Jaxb2Marshaller
        marshaller.setMappedClass(clazz);
        return (T) marshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(source)));
    }

    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(new HashMap() {{
            put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        }});
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[]{Partner.class});
        return marshaller;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Executable source code available at my [github](https://github.com/amithkumarg/solutions/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oss/shop/spring/assignment/jaxb/XmlTransformationNoRoot.java) repo.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the issue, The issue was with the Package name and I have seemed to be importing the wrong package, for which it was complaining about `partnerRequest` missing the `@xmlrootelement`.

So, finally, we need to be careful, when we have two classes of same name and when Importing with correct packages. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot 2, I uses the usually

```
@Bean
MessageConverter getMessageConveter() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath(ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName());
    Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<>();
    prop.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    jaxb2Marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(prop);
    jaxb2Marshaller.setCheckForXmlRootElement(false);
    return new MarshallingMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller);
}
```

However was still receiving the error. It wasn't until I discovered the I was trying to marshal complex type.. Once I wrapped this Object up in a

```
<xs:element name="..."
```

it generated an **@XMLRootElement** annotation as expected.