# Marshalling using ComplexType name instead of JAXB class name annotation

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb, annotations

I'm trying to consume a REST WebService, in which requests are sent as serialized XML objects

Here is an example

```
https://localhost:9985/fr_FR/api.ReceiveXMLmessage?xmlString=<TDetails_XCC OpeType="SOME_OPERATION"><TeamID>SOME_ID</TeamID></TDetails_XCC>
```

From this, I created the following XSD schema

```
<complexType name="TDetails_XCC">
    <annotation>
        <appinfo>
            <jaxb:class name="TeamDetailsRequestType"/>
        </appinfo>
        <documentation>Request team details</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="local:SimpleRESTRequestType"/>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="SimpleRESTRequestType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="TeamID" minOccurs="0" type="long">
            <annotation>
                <appinfo>
                    <jaxb:property name="teamId"/>
                </appinfo>
            </annotation>
        </element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="OpeType" type="string" default="some_operation">
        <annotation>
            <appinfo>
                <jaxb:property name="operationType"/>
            </appinfo>
        </annotation>
    </attribute>
</complexType>
```

This is the generated Java bean

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "TDetails_XCC")
@XmlRootElement public class TeamDetailsRequestType
    extends SimpleRESTRequestType
    implements Serializable
    {
    }
```

This is the code used to serialize the bean to XML

```
  TeamDetailsRequestType request = new TeamDetailsRequestType();
  request.setTeamId(546464L);
  request.setOperationType("SomeOperation");
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.mycompany.myproject.message.team");
  Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);
  marshaller.marshal(request, writer);
  System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

This is what the marshalled bean looks like

```
<teamDetailsRequestType OpeType="SomeOperation">
    <TeamID>546464</TeamID>
</teamDetailsRequestType>
```

And this what I wished I got

```
<TDetails_XCC OpeType="SomeOperation">
    <TeamID>546464</TeamID>
</TDetails_XCC>
```

I managed to get it working by using the QName class

```
JAXBElement jx = new JAXBElement(new QName("TDetails_XCC"), request.getClass(), request);
marshaller.marshal(jx, System.out);
```

But what I would like to know is if it possible to accomplish this solely from the XSD schema?

Thank you for your time

## Update

I'm guessing that the problem comes from the generated bean, because the problem is solved with the following bean

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement(name = "TDetails_XCC")
public class TeamDetailsRequestType
    extends SimpleRESTRequestType
    implements Serializable
    {
    }
```

So, how can I change my XSD to make JAXB put the ***name*** property inside of **@XmlRootElement** instead of **@XmlType**?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
<element name="TDetails_XCC">
    <annotation>
        <appinfo>
            <jaxb:class name="TeamDetailsRequestType"/>
        </appinfo>
        <documentation>Request team details</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <complexType>
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="local:SimpleRESTRequestType"/>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

As explained in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb), one of the many solutions to generate the **@XmlRootElement** annotation for a ComplexType, is to declare it as an *anonymous* ComplexType (ie wrapped in a named element)