# Java java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast exception when code generated using IntelliJ

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have created Java objects from XSD using IntelliJ Tools > JAXB > Generate Java Code From XML Schema using JAXB...

I am basically trying to generate Java objects from the XSD and then read a XML which would be compliant with this XSD into Java objects.

For my exercise, I am using the XSD from the six group website related to Credit Transfer Version 1.10.

However, when I try to run following code I see an exception : Java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast

```
public class Pain001Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "pain_001_Beispiel_1.xml";
        ClassLoader classLoader = new Pain001Tester().getClass().getClassLoader();

        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

        //File is found
        System.out.println("File Found : " + file.exists());

        //Read File Content
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        System.out.println(content);


        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try
        {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            ObjectFactory xmlMessage = (ObjectFactory) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(content));
            //ObjectFactory xmlMessage = (ObjectFactory) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(content)));

            //JAXBElement<ObjectFactory> userElement = (JAXBElement<ObjectFactory>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(content));
            //ObjectFactory user = userElement.getValue();

            System.out.println(xmlMessage);
        }
        catch (JAXBException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I think my issue is related to XMLRootElement but not sure if this is the issue. I understand the following stackoverflow question comes close to my problem but was not able to resolve my problem using couple of solutions highlighted in the stackoverflow case : [No @XmlRootElement generated by JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the error occurs in

```
ObjectFactory xmlMessage = (ObjectFactory) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(content));
```

jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal() does not return a ObjectFactoryt type, so you cannot cast the result to ObjectFactory. It returns a instance of the generated class which corresponds to the root element of the xml file.

Comment: Thanks Heri. You are correct. I found the issue and was about to post my solution but as you came first yours should be the answer.

Comment: Quick one Heri - do you know why annotating ObjectFactory with @XmlRootElement(name = "RootElement") did not work?

Comment: What do you mean by 'annotating ObjectFactory'? This is a generated class, do not touch it, just use it. Basically, you rarly have to care about ObjectFactory. Just use the classes which model your xml elements, and the marshaller/unmarschaller.

Comment: I initially thought this is some sort of a container class for the XSD and I can map the XML content response to this class. To be honest, when I initially looked at the code of this class my initial assumption did not make sense. Wondering whats the use and why would JAXB generate this class?

Comment: Step through it in debug mode and you will see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue (Heri pushed the button first, so he gets the cookies)

I changed the following :

ObjectFactory xmlMessage = (ObjectFactory) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(content)));

to

JAXBElement xmlMessage = (JAXBElement) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(content));

Then, instead of retrieving response to an ObjectFactory class I used the root element class generated by JAXB and it worked.

I am not sure why annotating ObjectFactory with @XmlRootElement(name = "RootElement") did not work but I now have a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your response like below

```
JAXBElement<OutputType> jaxBElement
```

and then get the object from it like below

```
OutputType outputType=jaxBElement.getValue()
```

Above piece fo example should work for you